# Remove To and BCC Addresses using System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms, system.net.mail

I'm upgrading a mass mailer application to use the new System.Net.Mail namespace. I'm also setting up AlternateViews for text and HTML versions.

Currently I'm using a DataReader to grab email addresses from the DB and send out the mails. In the old code, I would clear out the To and BCC properties at the end of the loop.

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

while (dr.Read())
{
    ....
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(dr["EmailAddress"].ToString()));

    if ((bool)dr["SecondaryNotify"])
        mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(dr["SecondaryEmail"].ToString()));

    // Send email
    ...
}
```

Apparently there is a Remove method that can be called on the To property of the MailMessage class mailMessage.To.Remove(MailAddress item) - I have determined this from intellisense. I have checked MSDN and cannot find an example of this usage.

Can anyone assist with syntax to remove To and BCC addresses for each iteration of the loop - after each email has been sent?

Comment: Then why you are adding To and BCC field at all, when you intended to remove them.

Comment: I have already send emails to those addresses - I want to grab the new ones for the next email.

Comment: Then you should move `MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();` to while loop, so that it will create new instance for every iteration and you don't have to remove/clear them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with a simpler solution. Just instantiate the MailMessage in your while loop. Then you have no need to remove anything.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    ....
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(dr["EmailAddress"].ToString()));

    if ((bool)dr["SecondaryNotify"])
        mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(dr["SecondaryEmail"].ToString()));

    // Send email
    ...
}
```

Comment: Currently sending out 2,000+ emails - no performance issue re-creating it every time?

Comment: How should I know? I'm not going to send 2000 emails to test it. Why are you pre-optimizing anyways? Write it so that it functions, then if it's unacceptably slow come back and take a look at what your options are.  My guess is that any performance penalty from re-instantiating the object is better than calling `.Remove()` a bunch of times (if that's even possible).

Comment: In the real world,  try sending out a few hundred mails and see what happens. You'll quickly be getting your boss to contact the companies who control the results ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in one code of mine...

Try this:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

while (dr.Read())
{
//Your code from HERE
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(dr["EmailAddress"].ToString()));

    if ((bool)dr["SecondaryNotify"])
        mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(dr["SecondaryEmail"].ToString()));

    // Send email
    ...
    //Then email delete from .To
    int iMessageInArray = mailMessage.To.Count(); //Finds the amount of emails in the array

    if(iMessageInArray > 0)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < iMessageInArray; i++)
       {
           mailMessage.To.Remove(mailMessage.To[0]); //When one line is removed, the next email comes in index 0 of the array.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var adresse = dr["SecondaryEmail"].ToString();
    int iMessageInArray = mailMessage.To.Count();
    if(iMessageInArray > 0)
    {
        foreach (var mailadress in mailMessage.To)
        {
            if (mailadress.Address == adresse)
            {
                mailMessage.To.Remove(mailadress);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe this code would error. You cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated over.